# Monitor for dead disk in linux

Tags: linux, monitoring, hard-drive, zabbix, alert

I have problem with backups disk that are not part of RAID or anything similar ( so no notifications from raid controller if disk dies). It happens that disk dies completely and only thing that is left i mount point that is inaccessible if you try to cd into it.

Is there a way for me to  monitor/get alert if disk dies ? 
I have zabbix at my disposal and I have found some smart scripts that can be used but I'm not certain if that will work since there will be no `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sda`  to use smart on when disk dies.

If anyone has some script to share or idea, I would be grateful on it.

Comment: Scary: I wouldn't trust a backup disk that dies without any warning from smart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var/log/syslog` should contain some information related to device disconnections; even without building stacks like ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) to analyze the log, you should be able to catch such events with tools like [sec](https://simple-evcorr.github.io/).

Comment: This is correct .I found a lot of info int he messages log about it. e.g.  kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): __ext4_get_inode_loc: unable to read inode block - inode=30598648, block=122162815    Do you think it would be possible to use zabbix to monitor this log and  send alert when it detects it ?

Comment: Not a Zabbix user, but I think the following is relevant: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/log_file_monitoring

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [nagios plugin](https://github.com/chicks-net/nagios-current/blob/master/plugins/check_read_only_fs) that you may be able to adapt to Zabbix.  I wrote it when we had a bunch of Linux servers going read-only because of random disk errors.  It helped us catch problems early and the code is there to test-write a file but we disabled that so the check could run as non-`root`.